# How to pass previous task state as parameter to another task within the Airflow Taskflow API?

Tags: airflow

I want to get the status of a SparkSubmitOperator, transform it to some value that my API understands and pass it within the payload of a SimpleHttpOperator so that I can update the job status inside my DB. I want to do this by using Taskflow API.

I wrote the code below but I get this error when I try to load it:

```
Broken DAG: [/opt/airflow/dags/export/inapp_clicks/export.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 1378, in set_downstream
    self._set_relatives(task_or_task_list, upstream=False, edge_modifier=edge_modifier)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 1316, in _set_relatives
    task_object.update_relative(self, not upstream)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'update_relative'
```

Code:

```
from datetime import datetime

from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from airflow.models import Variable

from airflow.providers.apache.spark.operators.spark_submit import SparkSubmitOperator

@dag(schedule_interval=None, start_date=datetime.now(), tags=["export", "inapp"])
def export_inapp_clicks():
    DEFAULT_NUM_EXECUTORS = 2
    DEFAULT_EXECUTOR_CORES = 3
    DEFAULT_EXECUTOR_MEMORY = "2g"
    DEFAULT_DRIVER_MEMORY = "1g"

    @task()
    def update_job_status(dag, ti, execution_date):
        jst = dag.get_task("export_inapp_clicks_job_submission")
        jsti = TaskInstance(jst, execution_date)
        xcom_value = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="export_inapp_clicks_job_submission")

        print("Task:", jst)
        print("Task Instance:", jsti)
        print("Task State:", jsti.current_state())
        print("XCOM Value:", xcom_value)
        
        # TODO: call API via SimpleHttpOperator

    job_submission = SparkSubmitOperator(
        task_id="export_inapp_clicks_job_submission",
        conn_id="yarn",
        name="{{ dag_run.conf['name'] }}",
        conf=Variable.get("export_inapp_clicks_conf", deserialize_json=True),
        jars=Variable.get("export_inapp_clicks_jars"),
        application=Variable.get("pyspark_executor_path"),
        application_args=[
            "--module",
            "export_inapp_clicks.export",
            "--org-id",
            "{{ dag_run.conf['orgId'] }}",
            "--app-id",
            "{{ dag_run.conf['appId'] }}",
            "--inapp-id",
            "{{ dag_run.conf['inappId'] }}",
            "--start-date",
            "{{ dag_run.conf['startDate'] }}",
            "--end-date",
            "{{ dag_run.conf['endDate'] }}",
            "--data-path",
            Variable.get("event_data_path"),
            "--es-nodes",
            Variable.get("es_nodes"),
            "--destination",
            Variable.get("export_inapp_clicks_output"),
            "--explain",
            "--debug",
            "--encode-columns",
            "--log-level",
            "WARN"
        ],
        py_files=Variable.get("export_inapp_clicks_py_files"),
        num_executors=Variable.get("export_inapp_clicks_num_executors", DEFAULT_NUM_EXECUTORS),
        executor_cores=Variable.get("export_inapp_clicks_executor_cores", DEFAULT_EXECUTOR_CORES),
        executor_memory=Variable.get("export_inapp_clicks_executor_memory", DEFAULT_EXECUTOR_MEMORY),
        driver_memory=Variable.get("export_inapp_clicks_driver_memory", DEFAULT_DRIVER_MEMORY),
        status_poll_interval=10
    )

    job_submission >> update_job_status

export_dag = export_inapp_clicks()
```

Comment: Hey @tunix! I was wondering if my answer below was helpful to you.

Comment: was definitely helpful to me, cheers mate!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following example, the first task will correspond to your `SparkSubmitOperator` task:

[image: graph_view]

`_get_upstream_task` Takes care of getting the state of the first task from the second one, by performing a query to the metadata database:

#### DAG definition, first two task:

```py
import json
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.utils.db import provide_session
from airflow.models.taskinstance import TaskInstance
from airflow.providers.http.operators.http import SimpleHttpOperator

@dag(
    default_args= {"owner": "airflow"},
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=days_ago(0),
    catchup=False,
    tags=["custom_example", "TaskFlow"],
)
def taskflow_previous_task():
    @provide_session
    def _get_upstream_task(upstream_task_id, dag, execution_date, session=None, **_):
        upstream_ti = (
            session.query(TaskInstance)
            .filter(
                TaskInstance.dag_id == dag.dag_id,
                TaskInstance.execution_date == execution_date,
                TaskInstance.task_id == upstream_task_id,
            )
            .first()
        )
        return upstream_ti

    @task
    def job_submission_task(**context):
        print(f"Task Id: {context['ti'].task_id}")
        return {"job_data": "something"}

    @task(trigger_rule='all_done')
    def update_job_status(job_data, **context):
        print(f"Data from previous Task: {job_data['job_data']}")
        upstream_ti = _get_upstream_task("job_submission_task", **context)

        print(f"Upstream_ti state: {upstream_ti.state}")
        return upstream_ti.state

    job_results = job_submission_task()
    job_status = update_job_status(job_results)
```

`job_submission_task` returns a `dict` that is passed to `update_job_status` via `Xcoms` using [XcomArg](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/xcom_arg/index.html) which is a main feature of Taskflow API. By doing so you get to avoid explicitly perfoming `xcom_pull()` and `xcom_push()` operations.

Once you get the `TaskInstance` object from `_get_upstream_task` method, you can return it and retrieve it again from the last task wich will perfom the HTTP request:

#### Final task, end of DAG definition:

```py
    task_post_op = SimpleHttpOperator(
        task_id="post_op",
        endpoint="post",
        data=json.dumps({"job_status": f"{job_status}"}),
        headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        log_response=True,
    )
    job_status >> task_post_op


example_dag = taskflow_previous_task()
```

Since the param `data` of `SimpleHttpOperator` is templated, you can retrieve the Xcom value from the second task using `Jinja`:
`data=json.dumps({"job_status": f"{job_status}"}),`

Execution logs:

#### Task_1:

```
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=manual__2021-08-20T23:15:15.226853+00:00
[2021-08-20 23:15:17,148] {logging_mixin.py:104} INFO - Task Id: job_submission_task
[2021-08-20 23:15:17,148] {python.py:151} INFO - Done. Returned value was: {'job_data': 'something'}
[2021-08-20 23:15:17,202] {taskinstance.py:1211} INFO - Marking task as SUCCESS.
```

#### Task_2:

```
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=taskflow_previous_task
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=update_job_status
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2021-08-20T23:15:15.226853+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=manual__2021-08-20T23:15:15.226853+00:00
[2021-08-20 23:15:18,768] {logging_mixin.py:104} INFO - Data from previous Task: something
[2021-08-20 23:15:18,792] {logging_mixin.py:104} INFO - Upstream_ti state: success
[2021-08-20 23:15:18,793] {python.py:151} INFO - Done. Returned value was: success
[2021-08-20 23:15:18,874] {taskinstance.py:1211} INFO - Marking task as SUCCESS.
```

#### Task_3:

```
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=taskflow_previous_task
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=post_op
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2021-08-20T23:15:15.226853+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=manual__2021-08-20T23:15:15.226853+00:00
[2021-08-20 23:15:21,201] {http.py:111} INFO - Calling HTTP method
[2021-08-20 23:15:21,228] {base.py:78} INFO - Using connection to: id: http_default. Host: https://www.httpbin.org, Port: None, Schema: , Login: , Password: None, extra: {}
[2021-08-20 23:15:21,245] {http.py:140} INFO - Sending 'POST' to url: https://www.httpbin.org/post
[2021-08-20 23:15:21,973] {http.py:115} INFO - {
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "{\"job_status\": \"success\"}", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
    "Content-Length": "25", 
    "Content-Type": "application/json", 
    "Host": "www.httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.25.1", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-61203789-0136b7557ba4e0116bb5e16d"
  }, 
  "json": {
    "job_status": "success"
  }, 
  "origin": "200.73.153.254", 
  "url": "https://www.httpbin.org/post"
}

[2021-08-20 23:15:22,027] {taskinstance.py:1211} INFO - Marking task as SUCCESS.
```

Let me know if that worked for you, I tried to use as many *Taskflow* features as I could.

Source: [Docs1](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/taskflow.html) [Docs2](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial_taskflow_api.html#adding-dependencies-to-decorated-tasks-from-regular-tasks)

#### Edit:

- Added `trigger_rule='all_done'` to `update_job_status` task.